# Azure Digital twins - What is the best tool to update an Azure Digital twin

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-digital-twins

I am starting to study and try to understand Azure Digital twins... and my next goal is to be able to send updates to my ADT instance, however, I want to simulate the following situation:

I have two NON-IoT Devices, in other words, I do not want to use IoT HUB since it might be a cost issue for me. So I need to send a payload to my ADT instance of the device "A", then I will read the state of this device, and based on that a action will be selected for device "B", and I will update the device "B" twin.
Last week I worked on a script that can send data from a simulated device to a digital twin instance. (following this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/how-to-ingest-iot-hub-data#code-try-7)

So I was wondering if you guys would have any advice, opinions, or insights to share on how I could “build this bridge” between the NON IoT devices and ADT…I am starting to look at it, but as you all know, it is very easy to get lost on material about Azure services, so if you have anything in mind that could narrow down my research it would be great.

On the link I mentioned there is a C# script that does this link between an IoT HUB and ADT, maybe that function itself could be the answer, but I know nothing about C#, so if the answer is there I would not see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can build DTDL models for objects that don't come from IoT devices. This is not only supported, but a really good idea as it will give your IoT equipment more of an 'ontology' by adding items like rooms, areas, lines to sort and query .

It will also give you access to other datasources such as workorders, vendors, links to document libraries. This is how you really make your ADT sing.

The best way to do this is to manage an ontology within a versioning tool such as Azure Devopps, which can deploy your ontology (with versions) to your various environments.

[Have a look at this sample I made](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/digitaltwins/azure-digitaltwins-core/samples/notebooks) using lines, people, areas, and tickets. It uses abstract objects from any source to create a simulation environment for real-time events.